# CreateJS/EaselJS: Bind two differnent kinds of operation logic to the same mouseEvent?

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I am doing a small game project named "puzzle game". Every piece of the puzzle should can be both moved and rotated. Whether I move the piece or roate the piece, I just do the same mouseEvent that move my mouse.
The differrence is that:
1) When the mousePoint is at the centre of piece , I will do pressMove;
2) When the mousePoint is at the edge of piece, if I move mouse, the piece will rotate according to the caculated angle.

But now, I don't exactly know how I do this.THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP.

For the roate, there is a example in this website.
(http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/11/18/GameDev-math-recipes...)

I want to do the same thing for rotating. And can move at the same time.

Comment: From the CreateJS community site where this is cross-posted: "I recommend making sub-elements that are hit targets. Depending on what is clicked, you can behave differently." http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/14067-how-can-i-bind-two-differnent-kinds-of-operation-logic-to-the-same-mouseevent

Comment: Yes. I have tried this, but the problem is when I hit the sub-elements, I have to move the whole container including the sub-element. When my elements become complex, it's a bit complicated to handle this.